# How to use quotes in bash scrips when a command in the script needs quotes too?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, backup, tar

I am attempting to make a script that will make a backup file of a video file in the same directory with the time stamp at the end of the tar file. The script is for demonstration purposes only, that is why I do not intend on sending the file to a different directory. Below is how far I have come with it.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd Compression_Play/
echo Me.$(date +%d_%b_%Y-%k:%M:%S).tar.xz
tar -I "pixz -9t" -cvf Me.$(date +%d_%b_%Y-%k:%M:%S).tar.xz 2017-03-23_01-13-02.avi
```

My problem is whenever I try to execute the script it gives me this:

```
Me.29_Mar_2017-22:03:49.tar.xz
tar: -9: (PROGRAM ERROR) Option should have been recognized!?
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

As best as I can tell the problem is with the quotes in my `tar` command. Is there a way to make the script so I can keep the quotes or substitute them?

Comment: It doesn't seem like an issue with quoting.  I am getting `tar (child): pixz -9t: Cannot exec: No such file or directory` on Ubuntu when I try your command.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was. When I try it with something else without the quotations like this example. It works.
`xz -9ve -T8 -k --stdout 2017-03-23_01-13-02.avi >Me.$(date +%b_%d_%Y-%k:%M:%S).tar.xz`

Comment: After toying with it a lot you are correct. I needed to replace the quotes with apostrophes and change the date part to `(date +%d_%b_%Y-%H_%M_%S)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your goal to make an archive, presumably preserving owner, file modes, file flags and ACLs, if available, then this should do what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
archive_name="Me.$(date +%d_%b_%Y-%k:%M:%S).tar.xz"
$(cd Compression_Play/
  tar -cvp 2017-03-23_01-13-02.avi |
  pixz -9t > $archive_name
)
```

Based on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/vasi/pixz#tarballs) for tarball compress/decompress for `pixz`, you will need to reverse the pipe to get your data out:

```
pixz -x9T < $archive_name | tar xvpf -
```

Comment: Im sorry. I for got to mention this tar command is meant to force tar to use all of my cpu cores instead of one by default. The command it's self uses the -I option which filters a programs like pixz through tar. This make tar use all 4 of my cpu cores. But I guess this command will not work through a bash script with the quotations in it. I just tested something similar and it works with out any errors.
`#!/bin/bash`
`cd Compression_Play/`
`echo Me.$(date +%d_%b_%Y-%k:%M:%S).tar.xz
xz -9ve -T8 -k --stdout 2017-03-23_01-13-02.avi >Me.$(date +%b_%d_%Y-%k:%M:%S).tar.xz`

Comment: I was unfamiliar with `pixz`, but I did a quick look-up and modified my answer to something that might be helpful.  `tar` essentially serializes a file system into a stream of bytes, so you can pipe its output into a compressor in a pipeline operation.  I have amended my answer to show this.

Comment: Thank you Greg. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Greg gave a good answer and it works very well. I also figured out another way after nocking my head on it for several hours and taking the things from the help I got.

`#!/bin/bash` 
`cd /home/apowell/Compression_Play/Test_Backup`
`tar -I 'pixz -9t' -cvf Me.$(date +%d_%b_%Y-%H_%M_%S).tar.xz /home/apowell/Compression_Play/Linux_Programs`

and this one compresses a little more by replacing pixz with just plain xz.

`#!/bin/bash`
`cd /home/apowell/Compression_Play/Test_Backup`
`tar -I 'xz -9ve -T8 -k' -cvf Me.$(date +%d_%b_%Y-%H_%M_%S).tar.xz /home/apowell/Compression_Play/Linux_Programs`